# Passing parameter from app get function of one file to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, get

How can I give a function that gets called in one file a parameter to use in another file. I am trying to create a RestApi with node.js and express.js. The file entry.routes.js contains the following code:

```
  app.get("/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/:AreaName/:Resolution/date/:Year-:Month-:Day", entry.findTwo);
```

However in this link there are some parameters inside the header as a token. I decode the token with the following code:

```
  app.use(
    jwt({
      secret: privateKey,
      credentialsRequired: false,
      getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
          return req.query.token;
        }
        return null;
      }
    }));
```

In the file entry.controllers.js the code is the following:

```
exports.findTwo =async function (req, res) {
   console.log(req);
   const correct =await getResults2(req.user.apikey);
   console.log(correct);
   if (correct==1){
       Entry.findByPars(req.params.AreaName,req.params.Resolution,req.params.Year,req.params.Month,req.params.Day, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err.kind === "not_found") {
            res.status(403).send({
              message: `No data`
            });
          } else {
            res.status(400).send({
              message: "Bad Request"
            });
          }
        } else{ 
            if(req.query.format!==undefined && req.query.format=="csv"){
                 const {Parser} = require('json2csv');
                 const json2csvParser=new Parser();
                 const csv=json2csvParser.parse(data);
                 res.send(csv);
            }
            else if (req.query.format==undefined || req.query.format=="json"){
                 res.send(data);
            }
            else { 
                res.status(400).send({
                message: "Bad Request"
                });
            }
          }

       });
   }
   else if (correct==2) res.status(402).send({ message: "Out of Quota"});
   else res.status(401).send({message: "Not authorized"});
}
```

In the last code when I do the following command

```
const correct =await getResults2(req.user.apikey);
```

where I try to access req.user.apikey . This parameter is available in other app.post commands in the entry.routes file but is not accessible in the other file. It passes as undefined.
For example in the entry.routes file the following code works perfectly:

```
 app.post("/energy/api/Logout",function(req,res){
        console.log(req.user.apikey);
        var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
        sql.query(`SELECT apikey FROM users WHERE apikey=?`,[req.user.apikey],(err,res1) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error: ", err);
                result(err, null);
                return;
            }
            else if (res1.length){
                res.status(200).send(" ");
            }       
            else res.status(400).send("Bad Request");
        });
  });
```

**Why doesn't the parameter req.user.apikey get passed in the entry.findTwo function on the file entry.controllers?**

Answer (score 0):

**The One reason** why you can only get the value from `req.user.apikey` in`entry.controller` when you send request to this endpoint:

```js
app.get("/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/:AreaName/:Resolution/date/:Year-:Month-:Day", entry.findTwo);
```

**It's because** you add `authorization` to the header, before you send the request.

‍ **It should be noted:** this `req.user.apikey` is **comming from the access token** that you provided in the header before sending the request.

Because you're using `express-jwt`, so, **every token that you include in the header will be decoded directly** and added to the `req` parameter, that's why you can access `req.user.apikey`.

So, if your question ❓ is why `req.user.apikey` can only be accessed in`entry.controller`, then the answer is because on your other route, for example:

**When you call this route: `energy/fire/logout`**

You didn't add authorization there.

So, **To be able to use `req.user.apikey` on your other route**, make sure in your `header` you have **added authoriazation**.

I hope it can help you  .